# kubernetes startup probe failed when deploying over Azure Kubernetes Services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, asp.net-core-3.1, health-check

I have asp.net core web api app where I have implemented health checks when we deployed the app to Azure Kubernetes Services and the startup probe gets failed.

> startupProbe:
> httpGet:
> path: /health/startup
> port: 32243
> failureThreshold: 25
> periodSeconds: 10

I can see that internally it's hit the endpoint with **IP address** overs http.

Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.22.148.185:32243/health/startup": dial tcp 10.22.148.185:32243: connect: connection refused

When I **removed** startup probe from YAML definition, then the startup endpoint is working as expected, here I am checking with **FQDN over IP** address

https://my-dns.com:32243/health/startup

What I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: what `scheme` value do you use for the httpGet startupProbe? it seems that you need to use `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: Yes, right sir, later I figured out that :) Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Raymond Since your comment is helpful, you can post it as an answer for better visibility.

Comment: Ok, will post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `https` instead of `http` for the `httpGet.scheme` value of the `startupProbe`.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond. one question, can you suggest how to test liveness probe for asp.net web api app? please check my question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70262289/how-to-simulate-asp-net-web-api-app-to-a-deadlock-or-hung-state