# How to simulate asp.net web API app to a deadlock or hung state?

Tags: kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi, kubernetes-health-check

I have an asp.net core 3.1 web api app. Can I write an end point by which if I call this the entire application will go into hung or deadlock situation? or a background task where I wrote some code to make this happen?

I am trying to test Kubernetes Liveness probe which I wrote as a health check endpoint in asp.net core web API application.

Thanks.

Comment: could you explain why you need to make it stuck in a deadlock / hang situation?

Comment: @Raymond, I would like to test kubernetes liveness probe and as a simulation I want the deadlock/hung state, so that POD/container automatically re-start. I have asked similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271108/is-deadlock-or-application-hung-state-possible-for-asp-net-core-web-api-applicat

Comment: ok posted an answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for testing some kind of hung situation, you can do something like making the thread / process to sleep. Make sure that the sleep period is greater than the `timeoutSeconds` configuration of the `livenessProbe`.

Or if you want to simulate the app to be down, you can also return http status >= 400 (ex: 500 / Internal Server Error) in the API response, so that livenessProbe will think the app is not healthy.

`livenessProbe` also has `failureThreshold` which is used to indicate how many failures to tolerate before K8 will terminate the pod, so if you want the pod to be terminated after just 1 failure, set it to 1.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond. This what I also know, but in run time I want to make application unavailable by making some deadlock or any other way. Please check my other question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271108/is-deadlock-or-application-hung-state-possible-for-asp-net-core-web-api-applicat, if you have some thoughts please let me know