# Is deadlock or application hung state possible for ASP.NET Core Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, deadlock

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API application which has a background host service where I wrote below code to simulate deadlock for the application:

```
public class Worker : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var a = new object();
        var b = new object();

        lock (a)
        {
            lock (b)
            {
            }
        }

        // other thread
        lock (b)
        {
            lock (a)
            {
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The app is running, but the app is NOT going to deadlock or hung state, I can still hit the web api end point and result is back to me.

Will it be possible to make the running web app into deadlock or hung state, so that NONE of the API give any 200 result?

Thanks.

Comment: just add a test which spawns mutiple threads say 100 and runs for like 10min, and u will know the answer

Comment: in its current form i would say no, unless u have something which is calling StartAsync multiple times from different threads...., seeing as i see IHostedService, my guess is this is called from 1 thread only.. so u will never have competing threads..

Comment: the answer is simply `Is deadlock or application hung state possible for ASP.NET Core Web API application` **YES** as the scope of what u mean isn't specific enough for it ever to be no, as its simply a feature of the language/usage. I think u should change the title, "for this code" and the answer is yes if called by multiple threads.

Comment: @Seabizkit, Thanks for your reply. Could you please give some example code?

Comment: example code for what?

Comment: @Seabizkit - I think user584018 means post an answer and explain yourself in more depth.

Comment: @user584018 i have stated serval things, 1 this is not called from a web request? so why is that part of the question, 2 the way u normal start a IHostedService is on 1 thread so there is no indication of how its being called from multiple threads. 3 its stated in such a way which doenst really form a gd question... aka would it be possible for me to jump 3 times. 4 a test could written but instead we left with IHostedServic. Its like the real question to op is what make you think this is being called by multiple threads? nevermind the actual question.

Comment: just add a test which spawns multiple threads say 100 and runs for like 10min, and u will know the answer. and like Raymond said add a delay to increase hold time. Example code for this... is op not capable of  writing this? seems a bit much to ask for an example... PO is very capable of writing on their own?

Comment: @Seabizkit - all of your comments are spot on. But, the code as-written will never deadlock. See my answer.

Comment: @MetroSmurf thx nice!

Answer (score 2):

As written, the current method will **NEVER** deadlock.

The lock objects are local to the method. Correct locking must use an object outside the scope of the method.

In the following revision, the lock objects are static to the class, and the locking adds a tiny delay to simulate work being performed. In this scenario, the app will deadlock with the 2nd entrance of the method.

```cs
public class Worker
{
    private static readonly object _a = new();
    private static readonly object _b = new();
    private const int _delay = 5;

    public Task StartAsync2( int n )
    {
        lock( _a )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _a1 enter" );
            lock( _b )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _b1 enter" );
                Thread.Sleep( _delay );
            }
            Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _b1 exit" );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _a1 exit" );

        // other thread
        lock( _b )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _b2 enter" );
            lock( _a )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _a2 enter" );
                Thread.Sleep( _delay );
            }
            Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _a2 exit" );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( $"{n}: _b2 exit" );

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And here's how to execute the `Worker` to cause a deadlock:

```cs
var w = new Worker();
var t = new Task[5];

for( int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++ )
{
    int n = i;
    t[i] = Task.Run( () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"{n} start" );
        w.StartAsync2( n );
        Console.WriteLine( $"{n} end" );

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    } );
}

Task.WaitAll( t );
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I tried to call the `Worker` in a asp.net web api controller endpoint and it's never returns a response which means it's deadlock, but this doesn't deadlock entire application, still I can call the other api endpoint. Thoughts?

Comment: I tried putting into background service as well, but entire application NOT going into deadlock or hung situation, still API endpoints are responsive and gives 200 :(

Comment: You'll need to add the `Worker` to the middleware pipeline that all requests go through. As each request comes through, the `Worker` must be invoked, and eventually with enough activity, the application will run out of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about ASP.NET, based on your code example, you can try to utilize something like Thread sleep / delay so that each thread doesn't lock the resource too fast.

probably something like:

```
        lock (a)
        {
            Thread.sleep(..duration..)

            lock (b)
            {
            }
        }

        // other thread
        lock (b)
        {
            Thread.sleep(..duration..)

            lock (a)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like code smell to me, forcing a pause like that.

Comment: yes, but since it's for simulation only, i think it's ok