# why my pods aren't healthy with the following error :Startup probe failed: Get dial tcp 10.224.0.85:80: connect: connection refused

Tags: deployment, azure-aks, startup, probe

my pods are not coming  up healthy with the following error  :

Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.224.0.85:80/": dial tcp 10.224.0.85:80: connect: connection refused

if i remove the startup probe from the deployment yaml it is working fine and coming up healthy

i tried to use https , and i tried to exec the pods to see any logs , nothing there

i tried to ping the ip of the pod ,  i got response , which means no network issue ,in addition there is no network policy defined

here are some command that  i run to verify

-> ps aux

USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

root           1 86.0 11.3 12716148 455996 ?     Rsl  10:48  51:38 dotnet MTSITE.dll

oi checked and find that somehow my application is not listening to the port 80

when i remove the startup probe and deployed  the syslog in the azure portal and find the following [syslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru4EA.jpg)

Comment: Please refer similar thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257046/kubernetes-startup-probe-failed-when-deploying-over-azure-kubernetes-services